# CakePHP - Allow null value for belongsTo foreign key

Tags: mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys, belongs-to

I have a table called notifications in my DB and a table called notes. Notifications has a foreign key reference on notes, I want CakePHP to recognize that this value can be null, do I need to set anything up in my model for this to take effect? Or only the constraint on the DB is required?

Comment: You should avoid null value in a Primary Key field.

Comment: It's a foreign key field I'm talking about, not primary field. Is it not clear from my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this fairly frequently. The only problem that you'll run into is that Cake stores empty values as empty strings which is bad for foreign keys. I wrote a simple, stupid [`NullableBehavior`](https://github.com/robwilkerson/CakePHP-NullableBehavior) to fix that.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? If its not too much trouble

Comment: Explain which? If you have an empty foreign key value in a record, it gets inserted as an empty string. This causes problems because an empty string is a value and it won't match anything in the parent table. The nullable behavior scans data being inserted and converts the empty values ('') to `null` if the database field is set to allow nulls.

Comment: If the answer to this is a link, can someone edit the answer to include it? ty! :)